# What is the total menu levels in the mmenu? I need 5 levels

Tags: html, css, asp.net, mmenu

I am using the mmenu (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/). I need to drill down to minimum of 4 levels, possibly 5.  Is there a limit to the levels the menu will drill down?  If so, how can I get to at least four levels of drill down?
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
     Private Sub RenderMSRows()

            Dim ReportName As String
            Dim ReportNamesub As String
            Dim ReportCategory As String
            Dim ReportCategorySub As String
            Dim ReportCategoryYear As String
            Dim ReportNameYear As String

            Dim HTMLString As String = ""
            Dim ulString As String = "<ul data-role=" & Chr(34) & "listview" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbCrLf



            'Get the Main Category

            HTMLString = HTMLString & ulString
            For Each mc In _ReportMasters
                ReportName = mc.Report_Name

                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<span title='" & ReportName & "'>" & ReportName & "</span>" & vbCrLf


                'Get the Sub Category List

                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<ul>" & vbCrLf
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf

                For Each sc In _ReportDetails
                    ReportNamesub = sc.Report_Name
                    ReportCategory = sc.Report_Category

                    If ReportNamesub = ReportName  Then
                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "<a href='' title='" & ReportName & "'>" & ReportCategory & "</a>" & vbCrLf
                    End If
***from here is where it will lock up if I don't quote it out***
                    'Get the Year List

                    HTMLString = HTMLString & "<ul>" & vbCrLf
                    HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf

                    For Each y In _ReportCategoryandYears
                        ReportNameYear = y.Report_Name
                        ReportCategoryYear = y.Report_Year
                        ReportCategorySub = y.Report_Category
                        If ReportCategorySub = ReportCategory And ReportNameYear = ReportName Then
                            HTMLString = HTMLString & "<a href='' title='" & ReportCategoryYear & "'>" & ReportCategoryYear & "</a>" & vbCrLf
                        End If
                    Next
                    HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
                    HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>" & vbCrLf
 ***to here***   
                Next
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>" & vbCrLf
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf

            Next

            HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>"
            Me.MenuBar.Text = HTMLString

        End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried using the menu, and seeing how many levels it supports?

Comment: There is NO limit to the level of submenus but more than 3 really requires thinking of an alternative structure. More than 3 is **very** heavy on user interaction and, IMO, provides a poor user experience. You might try looking for tips on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Richard Everett - I have tried to "see" how many levels and I really don't know what part of the coding "allows" so many levels.  I am new to jquery, this is a menu I like very much and I've tried to process a 3rd sublevel, which locks up with...this script is busy and such.  When I quote out the 3rd submenu (ul/li) it locks up.  My menu is built with database.  My other post has regards to that.  So...as far as I know, it allows 2 levels.

Comment: @ Paulie_D - I will check into your link.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @TanyaHammil - If you could edit your question to show us what you've tried then we should be able to help.

Comment: @Richard Everett - I made edit to question. The 3 levels so far are Main Category, SubCategory and Year. When I run it with the year, on load, it locks up/scripts busy...etc... When I quote out the Year section it will run, but no year, obviously. I will need to add a 4th level for the actual reports. This should be as far as I need drill down...but, it is locking up on the 3rd level, that is why I was asking if there was a limit to levels. I found out there isn't a limit. I understand about the user friendly...but, this is how the client wants it. –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working code that drills down 5 levels.  I found that the UL and LI elements needed to be placed in the right order.

Dim ReportNameSub As String
            Dim ReportCategorySub As String
            Dim ReportOrderSub As String

```
        Dim ReportNameYear As String
        Dim ReportCategoryYear As String
        Dim ReportOrderYear As String
        Dim ReportYear As String

        Dim ReportNameMonth As String
        Dim ReportCategoryMonth As String
        Dim ReportOrderMonth As String
        Dim ReportYearMonth As String
        Dim ReportMonth As String

        Dim ReportNameLocation As String
        Dim ReportCategoryLocation As String
        Dim ReportOrderLocation As String
        Dim ReportYearLocation As String
        Dim ReportMonthLocation As String
        Dim ReportSubNameLocation As String
        Dim ReportLocation As String

        Dim HTMLString As String = ""
        Dim ulString As String = "<ul data-role=" & Chr(34) & "listview" & Chr(34) & ">" & vbCrLf

        'Get the Main Category

        HTMLString = HTMLString & ulString

        For Each mc In _ReportMasterSorteds
            ReportName = mc.report_name
            ReportOrder = mc.Report_Order

            If ReportName <> "" Then
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<span title='" & ReportName & "'>" & ReportName & "</span>" & vbCrLf

                'Get the Sub Category List
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<ul>" & vbCrLf

                For Each sc In _ReportDetails
                    ReportNameSub = sc.Report_Name
                    ReportCategorySub = sc.Report_Category
                    ReportOrderSub = sc.Report_Order

                    If ReportOrderSub = ReportOrder And ReportNameSub = ReportName Then
                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf
                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "<span title='" & ReportName & "'>" & ReportCategorySub & "</span>" & vbCrLf

                        ' Get the Year List
                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "<ul>" & vbCrLf

                        For Each y In _ReportCategoryandYears
                            ReportNameYear = y.Report_Name
                            ReportCategoryYear = y.Report_Category
                            ReportOrderYear = y.Report_Order
                            ReportYear = y.Report_Year

                            If ReportOrderYear = ReportOrderSub And ReportNameYear = ReportNameSub And ReportCategoryYear = ReportCategorySub Then
                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf
                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<span title='" & ReportCategoryYear & "'>" & ReportYear & "</span>" & vbCrLf

                                ' Get the Month List
                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<ul>" & vbCrLf

                                For Each m In _ReportDetailMonths
                                    ReportNameMonth = m.Report_Name
                                    ReportCategoryMonth = m.Report_Category
                                    ReportOrderMonth = m.Report_Order
                                    ReportYearMonth = m.Report_Year
                                    ReportMonth = m.Report_Frequency

                                    If ReportOrderMonth = ReportOrderYear And ReportNameMonth = ReportNameYear And ReportCategoryMonth = ReportCategoryYear And ReportYearMonth = ReportYear Then
                                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf
                                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "<span title='" & ReportYear & "'>" & ReportMonth & "</span>" & vbCrLf


                                        ' Get the Name and Location List
                                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "<ul>" & vbCrLf

                                        For Each l In _ReportDetailReportandLocations
                                            ReportNameLocation = l.Report_Name
                                            ReportCategoryLocation = l.Report_Category
                                            ReportOrderLocation = l.Report_Order
                                            ReportYearLocation = l.Report_Year
                                            ReportMonthLocation = l.Report_Frequency
                                            ReportSubNameLocation = l.Sub_Report_Name
                                            ReportLocation = l.Report_Location

                                            If ReportOrderLocation = ReportOrderMonth And ReportNameLocation = ReportNameMonth And ReportCategoryLocation = ReportCategoryMonth And ReportYearLocation = ReportYearMonth And ReportMonthLocation = ReportMonth Then
                                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<li>" & vbCrLf
                                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "<a href=''  title='" & ReportMonth & "'>" & ReportSubNameLocation & "</a>" & vbCrLf
                                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
                                            End If

                                        Next
                                        'end of Name and Location list
                                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>" & vbCrLf
                                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
                                    End If

                                Next
                                'end of Month list
                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>" & vbCrLf
                                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
                            End If

                        Next
                        end of year list

                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>" & vbCrLf
                        HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
                    End If

                Next
                'End of subcat list

                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>" & vbCrLf
                HTMLString = HTMLString & "</li>" & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
        'end of cat list

        HTMLString = HTMLString & "</ul>"

        Me.menubar.Text = HTMLString
```